How to test writeToStream with sinon on Nodejs?
Here is the code I'm trying to test. I'm using sinon and supertest but if needed I can use Jest too. I managed to unit test without stubbing writeToStream but I do not think I should be doing it like that. Also for the status 500 case I'm not sure what I did.
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { writeToStream } from '@fast-csv/format'
import logging from '../utils/logging'

async getMyReport(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const data = [
            ['abc123', '112233'],
            ['bcd234', '223344'],
        ]
        try {
            res.header('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
            res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="data.csv"')
            writeToStream(res, data)
                .on('error', (err: any) => logging.error(err))
                .on('end', (rowCount: number) =>
                    logging.info(`You have ${rowCount} rows`)
                )
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send('I have an error!')
        }
    }

Here is my test code;
import request from 'supertest'
import app from '../app'
import { createSandbox, assert, match } from 'sinon'
import { PassThrough } from 'stream'
import * as csvModule from '@fast-csv/format'

describe('getMyReport', () => {
        it('should return correct headers and csv data', async () => {
            const res = await request(app).get('/v/myreport')
            const csvData = res.text
                .trim()
                .split('\n')
                .map((row) => row.split(','))
            expect(csvData.length).toEqual(2)
            expect(res.headers['content-type']).toBe('text/csv; charset=utf-8')
            expect(res.headers['content-disposition']).toContain(
                'attachment; filename="data.csv"'
            )
        })

        it('should return status 500 and "I have an error!"', async () => {
            const passThroughStream = new PassThrough()
            sandbox.stub(csvModule, 'writeToStream').resolves(passThroughStream)
            const res = await request(app).get('/v1/report')
            expect(res.status).toEqual(500)
            expect(res.text).toEqual('I have an error!')
            expect(res.headers['content-type']).toBe('text/csv; charset=utf-8')
            expect(res.headers['content-disposition']).toContain(
                'attachment; filename="data.csv"'
            )
        })
    })

For the first test case I stubbed nothing and just checked the length of the data. For the second one I tried to simulate the error case by stubbing writeToStream method with PassThrough object. But even if I stub it with anything else or do not resolve the stub, everytime it returns 500 and does not make sense to me.
Also I guess I need to test error and end events but whatever I tried, I did not manage to test it. Any ideas?
